# Accepting subtypes in generic sets

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to find a way in which I can return a generic set, which will accept subtypes. The code below returns a `Set<? extends A>` to which I'm trying to add a `B`.

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test {
    private static class A {}
    private static class B extends A {}

    public Set<? extends A> getSet() {
        return new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public void work() {
        getSet().add(new B()); // compile error
    }
}
```

Which results in the following error:

```java
Test.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(Test.B)
location: interface java.util.Set<capture#320 of ? extends Test.A>
                getSet().add(new B());
```

The [generic wildcard tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) states that `B` cannot be added to a `Set<? extends A>` because we don't know if `B` is a subtype of `A`, but I have just defined it as such. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's fundamentally impossible.

What if the method actually returns a `HashSet<C>`?
You just added a `B` to a set of `C`s.

The method's contents (`return` statement) are ignored when checking typesafety.

If you want to do this, you should just return an ordinary `HashSet<A>`.

Comment: I think the idea is that adding `B` to a set of `C`s would throw an error because `B` does not extend `C`. This may be impossible because it cannot be known at compile time.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't consider that. To be honest this is a distilled version of the problem I'm having. I'll find another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the matter is that, you can use wildcards in this fashion to iterate over different objects that extend a common parent and perform read operations, but that doesn't work if you want to write to the collection.

The reason is that the compiler cannot determine the runtime type of the collection that will be returned from the getSet() method. It will not parse the code you have written and try to arrive at that decision.

Answer (score 0):

> The generic wildcard tutorial states that B cannot be added to a Set<? extends A> because we don't know if B is a subtype of A, but I have just defined it as such.

That's not quite right. Say B and C each extend a. The getSet() method *might* be returning a  set of B or a set of C. You don't know. So you can't just add Bs to it. It might be a set of C and that would break the contract.

do the problem isn't that you don't know that B is a subtype of A, but that you don't know which subtype of A ? is.

Comment: Huh. Same answer from everyone :)